# How can SQLAlchemy association_proxy be used bi-directionally?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with Flask-SQLAlchemy to create a many-to-many relationship using [Association Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-pattern) and `association_proxy`, but I'm running into an issue: When I use `association_proxy`, I can set it up such that when I append a new instance to one side of the relationship, the Association Object will be created, but if I attempt to add an instance from the other side of the relationship, the Association Object constructor won't be passed the correct instance.

Here's a simplified example where `Club` has many `People`, and `People` have many `Club`, and the Association Object is a `Membership`:

```
class Club(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clubs'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('clubs_id_seq'), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    memberships = db.relationship('Membership', backref='club')
    members = association_proxy('memberships', 'club') # Can I pass a Person instance to Membership here? 
    created_at = db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('people_id_seq'), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    memberships = db.relationship('Membership', backref='person')
    clubs = association_proxy('memberships', 'club')
    created_at = db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Membership(db.Model):
    __tablename__ =  'memberships'

    person_id = db.Column('person_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('people.id'), primary_key=True)
    club_id = db.Column('club_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clubs.id'), primary_key=True)
    club = db.relationship('Club', backref='membership')
    joined_at = db.Column('joined_at', db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())

    def __init__(self, club):
        self.club = club
```

I'm using `association_proxy` because more than just the connection between `Club` and `Person` is important; I also want to be able to retrieve the `joined_at` property of the `Membership` if needed. In most cases, though, I only will query and append to `.members` of a `Club` or `.clubs` of a `Person`. In this example, I can create a new `Membership` by calling `person_instance.clubs.append(club_instance)`, but since the constructor of `Membership` can only take a single argument, how can I call `club_instance.members.append(person_instance)` if I were to work backwards? It seems lame that I could potentially iterate over `club_instance.members`, but have to remember not to `append()`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer in [this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/oYmRhmH5UCg). Here's the relevant portion:

```
class DossierTarife(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tarifer_dossier'
    IdDossier = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('dossier.IdDossier'), primary_key=True)
    IdAt = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article_tarife.IdAt'), primary_key=True)

    dossier = relationship(Dossier, backref=backref("tarifer_dossier", cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
    article_tarife = relationship(ArticleTarife, backref=backref("tarifer_dossier"))

class Dossier(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dossier'
    IdDossier = Column('IdDossier', Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...

class ArticleTarife(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article_tarife'
    IdAt = Column('IdAt', Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...

Dossier.LesTar = association_proxy("tarifer_dossier", "article_tarife", creator=lambda art:DossierTarife(article_tarife=art))
ArticleTarife.LesTar = association_proxy("tarifer_dossier", "dossier", creator=lambda dos:DossierTarife(dossier=dos))
```

I assigned my `association_proxy` directly within the class definition rather than doing it after the fact as above, and that worked well, too.

Also very helpful was [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071115/41728) describing how to properly delete Association Object rows:

```
user = relationship(User, backref=backref('user_to_groups', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
group = relationship(Group, backref=backref('group_to_user', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
```