# Automagically propagating deletion when using a bidirectional association_proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using a bidirectional `association_proxy` to associate properties `Group.members` and `User.groups`. I'm having issues with removing a member from `Group.members`. In particular, `Group.members.remove` will successfully remove an entry from `Group.members`, *but will leave a `None` in place of the corresponding entry in `User.groups`*.

More concretely, the following (minimal-ish) representative code snippet fails its last assertion:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText())
    members = association_proxy('group_memberships', 'user',
            creator=lambda user: GroupMembership(user=user))


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    username = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText())
    groups = association_proxy('group_memberships', 'group',
            creator=lambda group: GroupMembership(group=group))


class GroupMembership(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_group'
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)

    user = sa.orm.relationship(
            'User',
            backref=sa.orm.backref('group_memberships', cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
    group = sa.orm.relationship(
            'Group',
            backref=sa.orm.backref('group_memberships', cascade="all, delete-orphan"),
            order_by='Group.name')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(engine)

    group = Group(name='group name')
    user = User(username='user name')
    group.members.append(user)
    session.add(group)
    session.add(user)
    session.flush()
    assert group.members == [user]
    assert user.groups == [group]
    group.members.remove(user)
    session.flush()
    assert group.members == []
    assert user.groups == []  # This assertion fails, user.groups is [None]
```

I've tried to follow the answers to [SQLAlchemy relationship with association_proxy problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066749/sqlalchemy-relationship-with-association-proxy-problems/16071115#16071115) and [How can SQLAlchemy association_proxy be used bi-directionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501985/how-can-sqlalchemy-association-proxy-be-used-bi-directionally) but they do not seem to help.

Comment: Thanks or writing a good question with a working minimal example, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered [your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202016/344286) almost entirely by accident, as I was trying to figure out what's going on.

Because there wasn't any data in the db, I added a `session.commit()`. It turns out that (from the linked answer):

> The changes aren't persisted permanently to disk, or visible to other transactions until the database receives a COMMIT for the current transaction (which is what session.commit() does).

Because you are just `.flush()`ing the changes, sqlalchemy never re-queries the database. You can verify this by adding:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

And then simply running your code. It will display all of the queries that are run as they happen. Then you can change `session.flush()` to `session.commit()` and then re-run, and you'll see that several `SELECT` statements are run after your `commit`.

It looks like either `session.expire(user)` or `session.refresh(user)` will force a refresh of the user, as well. I'm not sure if there's a way to force the update to propagate to the other object without being explicit about it (or if that's even desirable).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! You're right that `.commit()`ing fixes this problem.

However, it seems undesirable to be forced a commit to achieve consistency. So I'll mark this answer as accepted in a day if no better solution is posted.

Comment: @mickeyh You can force SQLAlchemy to reload the data by issuing a `session.expire_all()`, but that just seems like a workaround.

Comment: @mickeyh or `session.expire(user)` or `session.refresh(user)` apparently also works.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll accept this answer since it contains several functional workarounds. It still seems funny to me to have to do something special (`commit` or `expire` or `refresh`) in order to maintain consistency within a single session tho. /shrug